# How to get the value of an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Trying to get the value of a specific tag in HTML, but I can't find a proper way to do it.

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<body id="en" class="that-great-class " number_id="1534" support="clp" source="desktop">
```

How can I get the value from number_id, support and source ?
Already tried this but doesn't work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("number_id");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your js is only slightly off, you are using `getElementsByTagName` which will get HTML elements by their tag e.g. `body` tag, `header` tag, `div` tag and so on.

You are wanting to get the attribute of the body tag so you first would need to get the body tag.

```
const bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

This gets all elements with the tag name of body and puts them in the array, but there should only be 1 body tag so you get the first.

You then want to get the attribute of 'number_id', to do this, you would do

```
const numberId = bodyTag.getAttribute("number_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[number_id="1534"]')
```

The related docs are [Attribute_selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1):

Your method name is incorrect it should be plural if you use tagName `getElementsByTagName`

But didn't actually correct with what you are trying to use

Getting element by `tag` means like `HTML` tags Ex - `li`, `h1` `body` not 
 their attributes

Use `querySelector` instead.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("[number_id='1534']")
console.log(el)
```

```html
<body id="en" class="that-great-class " number_id="1534" support="clp" source="desktop">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`var id = document.getElementById("en").getAttribute("number_id");`